# Simple Commerce set up, Public certificate

Tags: paypal, simple-commerce

EE 6.03

Ive enabled the Simple Commerce Addon, I've looked at the documentation on paypal:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNIntro/

and on EE:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/simple-commerce/paypal-settings.html

but it's not clear to me what information is required.

I think I need to generate a certificate on paypal and upload it to the server, or do I need to generate one locally?

Where should I upload it to?

Where do I get the details for:

Public certification ID

Public certificate path

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the page on the EE site that explains it,

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/simple-commerce/index.html

quite annoying as lots of pages refer to 'Please read the section on simple_commerce_encrypted_payments' without actually linking to it and searching the site doesn't help either!